# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nod.images.fluid') --

Tags: mapping, carousel, gatsby, simplemodal, contentful

I am new in Gatsby and trying to place a image carousel on a modal. I have an array of images on Contentful and cannot map the images.  I can do it outside of the modal but inside I can't reach to the array .

I tried to use different modals, different carousels but this is the best result that I can find.

These are the codes for carousel:

```
const CarouselUI = ({ position, handleClick, children }) => (
  <Container>
    {children}
    <Arrow onClick={handleClick} data-position={position - 1}>{'<'}</Arrow>
    <Arrow right onClick={handleClick} data-position={position + 1}>{'>'}</Arrow>
  </Container>
);
const Carousel = makeCarousel(CarouselUI)
```

These are the codes for component

```
const Product = ({ node }) => {
  const [showModal, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <figure>
        <Link href="/">
          <Image fluid={node.image.fluid} alt={node.title} />
        </Link>
        <figcaption onClick={handleShow}>
          <h4>Quick View</h4>
        </figcaption>
        <p>{node.title}</p>
        <p>{node.price}</p>
        <Modal className={product1Style.Modal} show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
          <section className={product1Style.modalheader}>
            <h1>{node.title}</h1>
          </section>
          <section className={product1Style.modalcontent}>
            <Modal.Body className={product1Style.row + ' ' + product1Style.center} closeButton>
              <div className={product1Style.col + ' ' + product1Style.colspan3}>
                <h4>{node.price}</h4>
                <div>
                  <button>Purchase</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={product1Style.col + ' ' + product1Style.colspan4}>
                <Carousel>
                  {node.images.map((nod) => {
                    return (
                      <Slide>
                        <Image fluid={nod.images.fluid} />
                      </Slide>
                    )
                  })}
                </Carousel>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
          </section>
        </Modal>
      </figure>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is my class:

```
class Product1 extends React.Component {

  render() {
      const ProductNecklace = this.props.data.productNecklace.edges

      return (
          <Layout>
              <section className={product1Style.lowerBody}>
                  <section className={product1Style.product1Necklace}>
                      <h3>Product1 Necklace</h3>
                      <div className={product1Style.productnecklaceimage}>
                          {ProductNecklace.map(({ node }, i) => (
                              <Product node={node} key={node.id} />
                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </section>
              </section>
          </Layout>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nod` is the image itself, it's the iterable object from `node.images`, you can name it however you want. Without knowing the data structure, it's impossible to figure out how the map should be, but I guess that should look like:

```
<Carousel>
  {node.images.map(image => {
    console.log(image)
    return (
      <Slide>
        <Image fluid={image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
      </Slide>
    )
  })}
</Carousel>
```

If you provide how's the GraphQL query, I will be able to infer how are the object and the arrays. Assuming that your `node.images` holds an array of images, inside each `image` you will need to access first to `childImageSharp` property before reaching `fluid`. As I said, your GraphQL query will be easier to debug. The `console.log` above the `return` statement will help you to know the nested properties.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I stucked in here a bit. I don't have childImageSharp property in my GraphQL. I can give childImageSharp property to the local images but for contentful I can't... I searched about it and there is some information about adding type with dummy context on Strapi but not Contentful..

Comment: Set the `downloadLocal` as true in the `gatsby-config.js` configuration https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/?=

Comment: I used another carousel but this time it worked. I am taking src property on my carousel images but it is ok. Thank you again..